# iOS - How to get slider's value in Settings Bundle

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a slider in Setting Bundles with Identifier called "volume"

How do I get the value of the slider to use in my app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NSUserDefaults` class for this. From the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5):

> Which option you choose depends on how you expect users to interact with preferences. The Settings bundle is generally the preferred mechanism for displaying preferences. However, games and other apps that contain configuration options or other frequently accessed preferences might want to present them inside the app instead. **Regardless of how you present them, you use the NSUserDefaults class to access preference values from your code.**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];//Synchronize With Settings App.
NSInteger mySliderValue = [defaults integerForKey:@"volume"];
NSLog(@"( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) %d",mySliderValue);
```

Comment: I know its an old thread. But figured I'd add a quick example of how I normally do it.